# How to speed up VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2010

The process of compiling, creating exe and running it is very slow on my machine(and also stopping the exe by the stop button). Its a windows forms app with a very simple form. I see that in Release mode it works faster, but not fast enough.

There is also slow down of IDE right after I hit the stop button, it really needs to think about something for at least 10seconds(I understand that I'm killing the app, but why VS cant just understand it and don't think about it?).

Maybe uninstalling something or disabling something?

P.S. This is slow only after a few runs, but I think I just got too old machine. I would rather not update it right now.

I have 2GB of RAM.

Comment: This is not really a programming question. You might be better off asking this on superuser.com. And you should include some data about your system.

Comment: Have you, by any chance, activated a deep code analysis ?

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Sounds like your computer is using the pagefile...

Comment: @TToni could you also migrate all visual-studio questions to superuser? its only 3.2k

Comment: @digEmAll How can I turn that off?

Comment: @IAdapter: is disabled by default, so it shouldn't be your problem. Anyway, you can find it here: "Project Properties --> Code Analysis"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the accepted solution is to upgrade to VS 2008.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP. My computer is quite old (6 years) and VS2008 is a huge "upgrade" compared to VS2010.

Comment: @IAdapter No, I meant *upgrade* to VS 2008! Seriously, VS 2008 is known to be quite a lot faster, lots of people have had trouble with 2010 performance. 2010 was a significant re-write, 2008 is super stable and polished.

Comment: This sage advice to 'upgrade' to a previous version of something has been around for ever, and is given about every new version of every popular bit of software.  It says much more about the innate conservatism of human beings than it does about development environments...

Comment: @will 2010 will get better over time just as xp did and just as vista did through service packs. Personally I'm happy with 2010 but 2008 is faster and if it does what you need why not wait?

Answer (score 5):

Release mode will make the compiler slower, if anything.   It generally makes the finished application smaller/faster, though.

VS2010 needs an enormous amount of memory, and if you have less than 3-4G, you're almost certainly being hit by that - that might be a cheaper upgrade than a new machine.

But all versions of the 'Visual' dev tools, right back to VC1.0, have been beasts that have required reasonably up-to-date computer specifications. I'm afraid that's just the way things are.

Comment: I have 2GB, thx for answer. Now I know what I need to upgrade :)

Comment: Interestingly, even on 4 GB some of my computers had some trouble. I recently added more memory to my desktop (which had 4 GB to start with) and VS2010 got noticeably faster.

Comment: @Mike - I concluded VS2010+R# was unusable for WPF development on a 32-bit OS, and so went to an 8G/64-bit machine to avoid the endless virtual memory problems - I definitely agree that 4G is not a sure fix.

Answer (score 2):

The BETA service pack worked wonders for me - lots of bits of VS2010 that were broken (like macros) started working and its significantly faster for me now - ymmv tho :)

[Microsoft VS2010 SP1 Beta Link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=11ea69cb-cf12-4842-a3d7-b32a1e5642e2&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question, but I can't find the duplicate. So in summary here's what the other one said :)

1) Get more memory, 4gig as a minimum.

2) Disable extensions

3) [A list of changes to speed things up 1](http://lennybacon.com/2010/10/18/UltimateGuideToSpeedUpVisualStudio.aspx)

4) [Might of found the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325630/ways-to-speedup-visual-studio-2010)

I love all my extensions, so memory is key to me.

Comment: I have a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054504/visual-studio-2010-how-to-reduce-its-memory-footprint