# Visual Studio 2010 "Not enough storage is available to process this command"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm fighting with VS 2010 and this error that seems to be very common in previous versions, but it looks like not everyone is having it in the latest version.
I've got VS 2010 SP1 and I'm getting this error quite often.

The problem is that it's not even enough to restart VS in order to make it go away, I usually have to restart my PC, and I'm losing a lot of time doing this (it's quite frequent)

I've got Windows 7 32bits (can't upgrade to 64 bits, the company doesn't allow it), and I can't do things like creating another solution (please don't reply this :) )

I've used the command to make `devenv.exe` `LARGEADDRESSAWARE`, but the error keeps on happening. 
My virtual memory size is set to automatic, and the weird thing is that VS doesn't even take 2GB of ram, so I don't know if the error is really because it's lacking memory, or if it's some bug in the program

Any ideas, things to try, something?

Comment: How many projects are in your solution and what language are they?

Comment: there are some projects, i'm not gonna say that it's a light solution. however, we can't change that either, it's defined like that in the company, and not everyone is having the same problem (some other guys have it but randomly and less frequently) so i can't propose to restructure the solution file. the language is english for all projects

Comment: I'm sure you have but just in case have you checked to make sure there is enough hard drive space available?

Comment: hi @JaredPar. yes, there's storage available. thanks for the shot though

Comment: Hey @DanielPerez i have this exact issue word by word. 40 projects in one solution, win 32 bit, and largeaddressaware enabled. Were you able to solve this eventually?

Comment: we upgraded the hardware (added SSD disks, 8gb RAM) and software (64 bit windows) and now it works, same configuration. I'd say that this is a visual studio problem, either because of a 32 bit system, or just because the hardware can't handle that much things in memory. Sorry but couldn't figure out any other way to solve it without changing the hardware. perhaps you could try installing 64bit windows if you can't upgrade hardware, that could help. let us know!

Answer (score 9):

I tried everything else as well. The problems continued to come back until I tried
http://blog.rongabriel.com/2010/03/08/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/

**Edit:** Link is dead, archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20100929160038/http://blog.rongabriel.com/2010/03/08/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/

> 1. Click on Start > Run > regedit & press Enter
> 2. Find this key name HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters
> 3. Locate IRPStackSize
> 4. If this value does not exist Righ Click on Parameters key and Click on New > Dword Value and type in IRPStackSize under the name.
> 5. The name of the value must be exactly (combination of uppercase and lowercase letters) the same as what I have above.
> 6. Right Click on the IRPStackSize and click on Modify
> 7. Select Decimal enter a value higher than 15(Maximum Value is 50 decimal) and Click Ok
> 8. You can close the registry editor and restart your computer.
>
> This can be found under MS KB https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/285089

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 
[Visual Studio 2010 -- how to reduce its memory footprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054504/visual-studio-2010-how-to-reduce-its-memory-footprint)

I think I got the best results when I turned off C++ headers index.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Check the output project type in properties. In my case it was changed to "Windows Application" though it was a "Console Application".

Switching back to console application solved my problem.