# Not enough storage is available to process this command (VS compile, runtime)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, silverlight

I am getting the following error in Visual Studio during the **build**:

> ...\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2868,9): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\someproject.dll" to "Bin\Debug\someproject.dll". **Not enough storage is available to process this command**.

And sometimes (if I could compile the solution) the following one in **run-time** when starting the web application:

> Could not load file or assembly 'SomeWebSite' or one of its dependencies. **Not enough storage is available to process this command**. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

I have already tried increasing [`IRPStackSize`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106167) to it's maximum value, but it did not help.

The problem seems to disappear temporarily after *rebooting*, but then it happens again.

- Windows 7 32-bit SP1
- Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- Silverlight 5

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592057/visual-studio-2010-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command

Comment: @TreyGramann Thanks Trey. Well, yes, except for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507853/system-error-code-8-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command About to try now.

Comment: @TreyGramann This one didn't help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126962

Comment: I have no idea. How many projects in your solution? Break it in half?  That would suck.  Longshot: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS? Not a happy day. Good luck!

Comment: @TreyGramann Quite a few, about 80 projects. And I already reinstalled VS a few weeks ago. The current problem has been there for a few days already. The day is good, it's just VS not in a good mood from time to time. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: 80!?!?!?!!!!  Ding ding ding!  Break it up.

Answer (score 0):

The work-around is to remove the **obj** folder from all of your projects inside the solution.

This folder can be created again upon building the project hence no harm to the project.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. It solves the problem sometimes, but only temporarily; after a while it comes back. And to compile the whole solution again takes quite long as well, so I'd rather fix the problem permanently.